# “Undoing” the bias of a resistor

Tags: amplifier, biasing

As you know, if you have an amplifier or comparator that can only output 0v to +v, you need to bias the input from -v to +v to +v to +v so that the output will produce the full signal range. But what if you wanted to connect the output of the amplifier or comparator to a speaker? The output range should be from-v to +v. How could you reduce the reference voltage back to a range that the speaker would take? I unfortunately cannot draw a schematic because I’m using a phone, but imagine an amplifier that needs to connect to a speaker, and needs to change the volt range from 0v to 20v to -10 to +10v

Comment: Blocking capacitor? Or use an amplifier with both poasitive and negative power supplies?

Comment: What if the output is a Schmitt trigger (comparator) that generates a 0v to +v output and needs to be converted to -v to +v input for an amplifier

Comment: Then you need a gain of two amplifier with offset. If you have a negative supply available it's easy to do with an op-amp.  Or simply use a 2nd comparator designed to have output levels of -v and +v. If you don't have a negative supply, you can amplify the signal to go 0 to +2v and then use a blocking capacitor.

Comment: My idea is use a comparator that compares v with a reference voltage of 1/2v, so that if it goes under the reference voltage it will create negative voltage, but if it goes above it will create positive output. Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A series coupling capacitor is used in some cases (for example, the [LM386](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf)).

[image]

As you can see, it's a relatively large capacitor for such a low power (typically well under 1W) amplifier.

Another method is to drive both sides of the speaker with active circuits, either analog or digital (eg. Class D).

For example ([analog](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4910.pdf)):
[image]

Or [digital](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tas5710.pdf):

[image]

(the capacitors on the output are bootstrap capacitors not coupling capacitors, related to creating a gate voltage internally).

Answer (score 2):

> How could you reduce the reference voltage back to a range that the speaker would take?

Use a DC blocking capacitor, as for example C2 in the schematic below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frtcSV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you can undo a DC bias with a compensating DC bias of the opposite sign, or one of the same sign applied to an inverting input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhDdkq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>